# "put binary" command is just outputting text instead of a binary file on LiveCode Server

Tags: livecode

I'm using LiveCode Community Server 8.1.2 on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter (running Apache 2.4)

I use the following code

```
put header "content-disposition: attachment; filename=" & tFileName
put header "content-type: application/pdf"
put header "content-transfer-encoding: binary"
put url("binfile:" & "../resources/documents/" & tActualFileName into tBinaryData
put binary tBinaryData
```

When included in a script called by a browser this code returns the data as text in the browser window rather than a pdf file that can be downloaded.

A few months ago I wrote this code and it worked, I returned to it today and it doesn't.

I've double checked and I'm sure it's correct but I have no idea what else could have broken it.

I've tested on
Chrome 59 on Windows 8.1 Pro
Chrome 59 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.5
Safari on iOS 10.3.2

Any help or guidance would be most welcome.

Edit:
Network headers from Chrome shown below
[image: Network headers from Chrome]

Edit:
Amended the code to remove the word "binary" from line 4 - this was generating an error which was producing text output at the end of the returned result - it hasn't resolved the problem - still getting text returned and "Content-Type:text/html" in the response header

Edit:
There are 2 blank lines at the beginning of the source (after using View Source, Ctrl-U on Chrome)

[image: View Source]

Comment: May be useful if you could grab the actual http response from the network viewer in chrome developer tools and see what exactly it is sending.

Comment: Excellent point Jeff - I've added the network headers in now. And on looking at the Response Headers "Content-Type:text/html; charset=windows-1252" looks suspicious to me. Though I definitely specify "put header "content-type: application/pdf" in the code

Comment: and no content-disposition either... random hunch, could you try declaring content-type first? It shouldn't matter but I've always put it first!

Comment: Another random though,  have you output any text before you set the headers?  I.e. you say it's 'included in a script' is it the first thing you do that might cause an output?

Comment: I put the 'content-type' header first - didn't help. I also noticed thaty line 4 of the code read 'put binary url...' - this isn't right and was producing an error which produced a text output - I thought I'd solved it but alas the error is gone and the output is still text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of working on this I now have a solution. It's a work around and I don't know what the actual problem is but for completeness it's worth posting.

The 2 blank lines before the "%PDF" code were the problem and after adding various debugging 'put' statements I tracked the offending code down the the following 2 statements

```
require ("codeSnippets.lc")
require ("databaseOperations.lc")
```

Each of these statements added an extra line to the output. I presumed the referenced files must somehow be outputting a blank line which goes unnoticed for a normal html page.

There's no code in them to do this so as a test I added the following code to the very last line of 'codeSnippets.lc'

```
put "test1"
```

And I added a similar line between the require statements

```
require ("codeSnippets.lc")
put "test2"
require ("databaseOperations.lc")
```

The output showed "test1" and "test2" on different lines. I can't explain what's happening between the last line of the Required script and the next line of the main script. If someone can shed light on this I'd be most grateful.

It's worth noting that I have other require statements that didn't show this issue. The following worked without producing an extra line

```
require ("../config.lc")
require("../resources/library/templateFunctions.lc")
```

As a work around I simply moved copies of the various bits of code I need for document download into a new file called "documentHandler.lc" and called the following

```
require("../resources/library/documentHandler.lc")
```

It all works perfectly now.